# Why do I occasionally get a 502 bad gateway error in my Express REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I am currently testing out REST API stuff using Express... It works and stuff, but when I keep calling requests and tweaking variables between each request, every 3 or 4 times it returns a 502 bad gateway. I am unsure why. I'll share my code although note that its just WIP code im using to test stuff out.

Here is the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const router = express.Router();

// Models
const User = require('../models/User');

// User Class
class UserEntity {
    // Initialize user
    constructor(username, password=false) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Get Display Name
    async getDisplayName() {
        try {
            const displayCheck = await User.findOne({username: this.username})
            if (!displayCheck) {
                return false;
            }
            
            return displayCheck.displayName;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error while getting display name: " + err);
            return false;
        }
    }

    async login() {
        // 0 = Success
        // 1 = User not found
        // 2 = Incorrect password
        // 3 = Error or class missing password, check console 

        if (this.password != false) {
            // Find user
            try {
                const userCheck = await User.findOne({ username: this.username });
                if (!userCheck) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error while checking if username exists: " + err);
                return 3;
            }

            // Check password
            try {
                const userCheck = await User.findOne({username: this.username})
                if (!userCheck) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(this.password, userCheck.password);
                    if (!validPass) {
                        return 2;
                    }

                    // logged in!
                    return 0;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error while checking password: " + err);
                return 3;
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Class missing password");
            return 3;
        }
    }
}

router.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    const user = new UserEntity("nero", "iamcool4");
    const login = await user.login();
    if (login == 0) {
        res.send("Logged in!");
    } else if (login == 1) {
        res.send("User not found");
    } else if (login == 2) {
        res.send("Incorrect password");
    } else if (login == 3) {
        res.send("Error");
    }
})
```

Comment: Unrelated to the initial question but you should return the correct HTTP Status for each case, instead of return 0, 1, 2,... you should return 200, 404, ...
here is a list: https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

Otherwise can you edit your post with the command used to run the server ?

Comment: Bad gateway usually means a connection problem between the web server and some other server (database for example)

Comment: Ye Im just testing out code for fun. I know to return http status codes n json back. im just playing around with code. ive made fully working rest api's in express before just trying to recreate one but adding classes in javascript